# URL with trailing slash breaks layout - how can I fix this without using base tag?

Tags: url, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am developing a website, and I have set up the following htaccess rules

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)?$ index.php?page=$1
#RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)?$ index.php?page=$1&post=$2
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ index.php?pagename=$1
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ index.php?pagename=$1&post=$2
```

This ensures that instead of `http://www.mysite.com/index.php?page=2` showing the page

I get to use the friendlier method of `http://www.mysite.com/about-us`

*** note I have not included a trailing slash.**

In the page my css files are included as:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and located at `www.mysite.com/css/style.css`

And this works well, however if I want to include a trailing slash (i.e. `http://www.mysite.com/about-us/`)

Then my css files do not load and I get an error where the Firefox source browser says:

The requested URL `http://www.mysite.com/about-us/css/style.css` was not found on this server.

This is because the page is determining about-us to be a directory instead of a page.

I am not keen to use the basehref tag like `<base href="http://www.mysite.com/" />`

**Are there any other options?**

Answer (score 0):

Relative URLs are resolved from a base URL that is the URL of the document the relative URL is used in if not specified otherwise.

Now to fix this incorrect reference, you have two options:

- change the base URL using the `BASE` element,
- change the reference

  - by adjusting the relative URL path to the base URL path, or
  - by using just an absolute URL path, or
  - by using an absolute URL.

Since you don’t want to use the `BASE` element, you will probably need to adjust the URL you are using to reference the external resource.

The simplest would be to use the absolute URL path `/css/style.css` instead so that it is independent from the actual base URL path.